# How can I remove a user from public group 1 when s/he is added to public group 2?

Tags: trigger, automation, public-group

I have a business requirement to show all records of a custom object to all users except for a small group called 'reviewers'. This requirement runs against the grain of standard SFDC sharing, so it's not straightforward to support.

One approach is to add all users *except* the reviewers to a public group Show and the reviewers to a public group Hide. The size of our org necessitates automating membership of Show.

It's easy to add members on user creation and deactivation by using a trigger on the User object. But I also need to remove users from Show if they are added to Hide. It does not appear possible to write a trigger on GroupMember to do this: Group and GroupMember do not appear in the SObject list when creating a new trigger in the developer console.

What would be other approaches to meeting this requirement?

Comment: is it okay to change the design. Means change custom object owd is private and then create a criteria based sharing rule. will it work?

Comment: I should have said that the starting point is that OWD for this custom object is Private. Sharing rules could then be used to widen visibility to a group of users which excludes the reviewers. My concern is that with thousands of users and only a handful of them being users, automation is the only way to make this approach work, and it's not clear whether I can automate public-group membership to move users between the Show and Hide groups as personnel changes occur.

Comment: Just use a checkbox on user for "reviewer" and use visual workflow to add/remove user from groups when checkbox is checked / unchecked.  Also I assume having a separaterole in the hierarchy for reviewers is out of the question?  That would solve the issue with standard role based sharing.

Answer (score -1):

The object names are actually `CollaborationGroup` and `CollaborationGroupMember`. You can create triggers on both.

Comment: CollaborationGroup represents a Chatter group (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm). Public groups are Group objects where Type=Standard (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm)

Comment: Ah, so it is. I didn't catch that in the docs I read. You can definitely access it in Apex with Group and GroupMember. You could create a scheduled job that runs and cleans up the groups. It wouldn't be real time like a trigger but you could set it to run as frequently as every hour to clean up memberships.

Comment: Useful to know - that would be frequent enough for our purposes. Thanks!  The Group vs. CollaborationGroup thing caught me out once before; it's too easy to get confused over those two :>)